# When angle bracket is converted to mnemonics &gt;?

Tags: javascript, html, r

### Context

Following this [chapter](https://book.javascript-for-r.com/widgets-first) in Javascript for R online book I cannot reproduce the last example and
I guess that is because `<` is transformed into `&gt;`.

### Reproducible steps

---

#### Packages needed

```
library(usethis)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
library(htmlwidgets)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
library(shiny)
```

---

#### Create the widget

```
create_package("playground")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
scaffoldWidget("play")
```

---

#### Modify the code in `play.R`

change this section:

```
  # forward options using x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  x = list(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      message = message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  )
```

into this:

```
  # forward options using x                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  x = list(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      message = as.character(message)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  )
```

---

#### Load package and use widget

```
document(); load_all()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
play(h2("Some text!"))
```

---

### Result

[image]

---

#### Expected

Formatted header

---

### Effort

When inspecting the text, one can copy/paste the content of the div and see:

```
<div class="play html-widget html-fill-item-overflow-hidden html-fill-item html-widget-static-bound" id="htmlwidget-4a78c11ab194f4375219" style="width:960px;height:500px;">&lt;h2&gt;qwer&lt;/h2&gt;</div>
```

I guess the issue is coming from the `&gt;` that replaces the '>' but I cannot see:

1. where it is happening
2. If it is expected
3. If something has changed since the writing of the book

---

#### play.js

```
HTMLWidgets.widget({

  name: 'play',

  type: 'output',

  factory: function(el, width, height) {

    // TODO: define shared variables for this instance

    return {

      renderValue: function(x) {

        // TODO: code to render the widget, e.g.
        el.innerText = x.message;

      },

      resize: function(width, height) {

        // TODO: code to re-render the widget with a new size

      }

    };
  }
});
```

Comment: I think `shiny::HTML()` will help.

Comment: What do you have in the JavaScript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` in your code. This means you set the contents in such a way that the displayed text at the end is `<h2>qwer</h2>`, so the angle brackets get escaped. You seem to want to actually set HTML contents though, so the angle brackets should get interpreted as HTML tags. That's why you need `innerHTML` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript file receives the character string `"<h2>qwer</h2>"`. You have to parse it to HTML. Since **jQuery** is available in **htmlwidgets**, you can use [`$.parseHTML`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/) (applied to `$(el)$`, the jQuery selection of the htmlwidgets element).

Comment: I cannot see what you mean by that. I have attached the JS file to the question.

Comment: @pietrodito Sorry, this is `el`, not `e`. You can also use `ìnnerHTML`, as in the book you linked.

Comment: AARRGGHH. You are right the answer is in the book... READ THE DOCS!